# Android WallpaperManager method "soft-bricking" user's phones and causing an unresponsive device

Tags: java, android

I've had 2 users in the last 2 days report that their phones crashed and remained unresponsive until performing a factory restore while using my app, at the same point. I've found this occurs with other similar apps and believe the reports to be credible, but no other solutions or discussions anywhere. (Google & OnePlus on Android 9.0 SDK 28)

They both describe a blank, black, and unresponsive lockscreen that persists even in safe mode. Only the power button and power menu works while in this "stuck" state. Both users are unrooted, use the same settings, and use the default Android launcher.

Following their reports, the only "dangerous" thing that occurs during their usage is:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp, null, false, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
```

This runs within an AsyncTask and does nothing special other than the above. I expect it to be an anomaly since it appears it has only been reported twice out of a few thousand users, but it's concerning. I'm not sure if it's an issue with `Bitmap` leaks, SystemUI, or Android itself.

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue? I've commented the other answer.

Comment: @simone_s1994, I haven't solved this issue yet, I haven't seen any crash logs or had it happen to myself. Is this happening to your own device? I'm willing to work with you to help us find a solution

Comment: no crash, no log, nothing. My app changes wallpaper correctly but there is a little freeze. A my user has found this problem with a Nokia 8 with Android Pie (I've a Pixel 3 with feb update) and the problem seems to solve only if I choose the light theme on my device, instead the dark one or the automatic one. I don't know if it's a problem of Android Pie.

Comment: @simone_s1994, My users were all on Android Pie as well, and Firebase/Play Console doesn't list any crash reports for their devices. I've opened a ticket with Google issue tracker, have you tried any other bug logging methods?

Comment: No, nothing....

Comment: @simone_s1994, I asked the 3 users who experienced the issue with my app, all 3 of them use Dark mode/automatic as well.. Very interesting, I will keep you updated - feel free to email me at bryanwalsh00@gmail.com if you want to continue the convo outside of this thread

Answer (score 0):

Yep. setBitmap() is dangerous, image can be too large. If you let users to setup own wallpapers, check image dimensions and resize.

Comment: Mh, same problem for me. I've tried with a bitmap of 1000x2000px on my Pixel 3, the problem occurs only with android 9. Maybe it's related to the theme, if I choose "light theme", my app works fine.

Comment: Edit: same problem with a bitmap of 300x600. And the problem happens only if I set the wallpaper on the home screen.